# Настройка адаптивного меню

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Возможно у кого-то есть время посмотреть [этот пример](http://codepen.io/brezze/pen/WOdqZQ). Почему меню по клику на гамбургер снизу вверх выезжает? Нужно, чтобы плавно вниз съезжало.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 $(".hamburger").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("is-active")
  $(".main-nav").slideToggle();
 });
});
```

```css
.top-line__container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.phone a {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.main-nav__list {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.main-nav__list li + li {
    margin-left: 22px;
}

.main-nav__list li + li a {
    color: #000;
}

.main-nav__list .active .main-nav__link {
    color: #F09E10;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #F09E10;
}

.main-nav__link {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.main-nav__link:hover {
    color: #F09E10;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #F09E10;
}

.hamburger {
    padding: 15px 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition-property: opacity, filter;
    transition-duration: 0.15s;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
    font: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    text-transform: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: visible;
}

.hamburger:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.hamburger-box {
    width: 40px;
    height: 24px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.hamburger-inner {
    display: block;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -2px;
}

.hamburger-inner,
.hamburger-inner::before,
.hamburger-inner::after {
    width: 40px;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    transition-property: transform;
    transition-duration: 0.15s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
}

.hamburger-inner::before,
.hamburger-inner::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
}

.hamburger-inner::before {
    top: -10px;
}

.hamburger-inner::after {
    bottom: -10px;
}

.hamburger--squeeze .hamburger-inner {
    transition-duration: 0.075s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
}

.hamburger--squeeze .hamburger-inner::before {
    transition: top 0.075s 0.12s ease, opacity 0.075s ease;
}

.hamburger--squeeze .hamburger-inner::after {
    transition: bottom 0.075s 0.12s ease, transform 0.075s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
}

.hamburger--squeeze.is-active .hamburger-inner {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transition-delay: 0.12s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
}

.hamburger--squeeze.is-active .hamburger-inner::before {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: top 0.075s ease, opacity 0.075s 0.12s ease;
}

.hamburger--squeeze.is-active .hamburger-inner::after {
    bottom: 0;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transition: bottom 0.075s ease, transform 0.075s 0.12s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top-line">
    <div class="wrapper">
       <div class="top-line__container">
         <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="img/Logo.png" alt="alt"></a>
       <nav class="main-nav">
        <ul class="main-nav__list">
           <li class="active"><a href="#" class="main-nav__link">Главная</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="main-nav__link">О компании</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="main-nav__link">Оценка</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="main-nav__link">Сделки M&A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="main-nav__link">Бухгалтерские услуги</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="main-nav__link">Контакты</a></li>
        </ul>
     </nav>
     <div class="phone">
       <a href="tel:+7495009956">
         <span>+7 (495) 00-99-56</span>
       </a>
      </div>
      <a class="hamburger hamburger--squeeze">
        <span class="hamburger-box">
          <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
        </span>
         </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".hamburger").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("is-active")
        $(".main-nav").slideToggle(1000);
    });
});
```

Попробуй так: `.slideToggle(1000)`. Думаю поможет. В скобках создается время анимации )

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но там проблема была в другом, нужно было просто поменять местами блоки через флекс ордер, и все заработало как нужно.